# javascript: How to pass array as string substitution vales

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass array of string as string substitution.

```
var s1 = "hello %s, i am %d years old";
var s2 =[John,24];
```

Expected result string: `hello John, i am 24 years old.`

I tried `console.log(s1,s2.tostring())` but `s2.string()` converts into a string and not two induvidual strings.
Can anyone please help ?

Comment: what if the values in the array are switched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just spread the array:

```js
var s1 = "hello %s, i am %d years old";
var s2 =["John",24];

console.log(s1, ...s2)
```

Comment: this is amazing. 1 question, can we do it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your use case is, but if you just want to substitute variables inside a string you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
var name = "John";
var age = 24;
var s1 = `hello ${name}, i am ${age} years old`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch you array using index

let s2 =["John",24];

output "Hello "+s2[0]+", I'm "+s2[1]+" years old";
console.log(output)

Output : hello John, i am 24 years old.